# Make Chartkick wait for data to populate from Firebase before rendering chart

Tags: vue.js, chartkick

I'm using chartkick in my Vue project. Right now, the data is loading from Firebase after the chart has rendered, so the chart is blank. When I change the code in my editor, the chart renders as expected, since it's already been retrieved from Firebase. Is there a way to make chartkick wait for the data to load before trying to render the chart? Thanks!

Line-Chart Component:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loaded">
    <line-chart :data="chartData"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VueChartKick',
  props: ['avgStats'],
  data () {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      chartData: this.avgStats
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loaded = true
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent:

```
<template>
  ...
  <stats-chart v-if="avgStatsLoaded" v-bind:avgStats="avgStats" class="stat-chart"></stats-chart>
  <div v-if="!avgStatsLoaded">Loading...</div>
  ...
</template>

<script>
import StatsChart from './StatsChart'

export default {
  name: 'BBall',
  props: ['stats'],
  components: {
    statsChart: StatsChart
  },
  data () {
    return {
      avgStatsLoaded: false,
      avgStats: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedStats: function () {
      return this.stats.slice().sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getAvgStats: function () {
      this.avgStats = this.stats.map(stat => [stat.date, stat.of10])
      this.avgStatsLoaded = true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getAvgStats()
  }
}
```

Comment: show me the code of your line-chart component

Comment: @jacky - sure, the child component (now renamed to line-chart) is the line chart component.Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your code of StatsChart component:
you may use props directly

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loaded">
    <line-chart :data="avgStats"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'VueChartKick',
  props: ['avgStats'],
  data () {
    return {
      loaded: false,
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loaded = true
  }
}
```

Comment: In your code of child components,receives data from parent component through the chartData property, but the receiving only in creation, there is no binding relation, so, when the data from asynchronous request, chartData's value  of child components will not change, unless you use a watch to monitor changes